# a una lista de numeros en en un archivo.txt sumarle una cantidad x y que se guarde el cambio

Tags: python, bucle-for, txt

estas son las edades
22
24
17
18
17
19
17
23
25
17
18
19
19
17
19
22
21
19
20
17

y están en un archivo "edades.txt" y a cada una de esas edades, en python usando el ciclo for tengo que sumarles una cantidad x en positivo, si es un numero negativo me debe de arrojar un mensaje que no puedo restar, y si no es numérico, me debe decir que no se puede realizar la operación.

ya lo he intentado y se me borran los números y queda vacío.

Comment: Cual seria tu código? Sin ver el código, no hay manera de saber la causa del error.

Answer (score -1):

```
archivo = "C:\\Users\\mario\\Documents\\tareas python\\tarea12_333827\\edades.txt"

f = open(archivo,"r")

print (f.read())

for linea in f:

     x = int(input("Dame la cantidad de años trancurridos:"))

     if x >0:

        f= open (archivo,"w") #en esta parte no se como darle la orden que sume

        print (f.read())

     elif x <0:

        print ("No se pueden quitar años al tiempo transcurrido")
        
     else:
        raise ValueError
        print('Error dato no valido')
f.close()
```

Ese es mi código, hasta el momento lo borro y lo vuelvo a hacer, sin un tutor fijo se me ha hecho bastante difícil, pues siempre me dan la información que tengo de base, leer como es la estructura del bucle `for`, leer sobre archivos externos lectura escritura crear, pero hay partes que no termino de entender

Gracias por contestar.

Comment: No es recomendable dar respuesta a preguntas incompleta/mal formuladas. Probablemente tampoco sea lo que el OP necesita.

Comment: Lo único que hace tu código es imprimir la línea que lee del archivo como cadena de texto, en el loop `for linea in f` tendrías que interaccionar con la variable `linea` para poder de alguna forma modificar los valores, y además necesitas convertir cada número a un entero `int`  porque de otra forma no podrías operar sobre él. Lo mejor sería que volvieras a formular tu pregunta con un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) es decir la parte del código en la que tienes dudas, algunos datos de entrada y salida de ejemplo.

Comment: Sumando a lo que dice friveroll, ten en cuenta que aqui van nuestras respuestas. Si querés agregar algo a la pregunta, deberías de editarla.

Comment: @friveroll yo diría que un emcv NO es un fragmento del código, si no otro código basado en el código original. Tu definición, además, no incluye el concepto de completo y verificable. Pero seguramente querías transmitir esto mismo.

Comment: Les agradezco los comentarios, dar un ejemplo de algo similar no lo tengo puesto le he buscado para de ahí basarme, la pregunta que hago es resumen del problema que me plantean, donde solo me dan las edades, me permiten hacer el archivo txt manual, pero de ahí el programa me pedirá un numero positivo el cual será sumado a todos los números de la lista de edades y cada vez que ejecute lo va a leer primero después me pedirá un numero y se sumara y se guardara el cambio.